# Determining clusters of time series

Tags: time-series, clustering, dynamic-time-warping

I have been given time series of N stock prices and time series of K sectoral indices. (Sectoral index is index made from all stocks belonging to that sector.) I have not been given names of any of those stocks or indices. I want to know which stocks belong to the same sector and sectoral indices. I am able to cluster the stocks. But how should I decide which sectoral index time series they correspond to? Should I just cluster stocks and indices together (N+K timeseries) instead of clustering N stocks independently? Will that be correct approach?

Comment: So the sectoral index time-series is a sum of the individual stock price time-series ? Do you have the complete set of time-series of each sectoral index?

Comment: Sectoral index might not simply be plain sum of individual stocks. Exchanges usually use some kind of formula, for example the one stated [here](https://choiceindia.com/blog/how-stock-market-index-is-calculated). For all stocks and indices, I have same number of data points.